# Cast do tipo byte em inteiro

Tags: java, tipagem

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
public class Principal {
     public static void main(String[] args){

      int i = 10;
      byte b = 5;
      b = (byte)i;
      b += i;
      i = b;

      System.out.println( i );
      }
}
```

Sei que o valor retornado em **b = 20**.

Mas por que? Gostaria de entender o que acontece quando coloco o `cast(byte)` no `int`.

Questão 127 página 4 [concurso](http://www.cespe.unb.br/concursos/MEC_15_TEMPORARIO/arquivos/178MECPS_001_01.pdf)

Comment: `Questão 127 do concurso`, coincidentemente, o valor máximo possível de armazenar no byte :D

Comment: @Bia, atualizei minha resposta baseado na edição que você fez na pergunta.

Comment: @Bia o que significa esse "julgue"? É para dizer o que acha de cada afirmação? É para dizer se ela está errada?

Comment: @bigown julgar se a afirmação é correta ou não.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes de responder a pergunta em si, é importante mencionar que essa instrução `byte b = 5` não está alterando em nada o resultado. Poderia ter sido feito direto `byte b = (byte)i`.

Sobre o resultado, é preciso compreender os tipos envolvidos na pergunta, principalmente o tipo `byte`.

Em Java, o tipo `byte` possui sinal e tem tamanho de 1 byte, portanto, 8 bits. Utilizando 8 bits é possível mapear 256 caracteres, nesse caso, números inteiros. Como a variável tem sinal, então o intervalo vai de [-128,127].

Dito isso, se o inteiro que você está fazendo *cast* para `byte` estiver nesse intervalo, então ele será impresso corretamente, caso não esteja, acontecerá um overflow na variável do tipo `byte` e o que será impresso será um número nesse intervalo, mas não o `int` para o qual você está fazendo *cast*.

Veja isso: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

**Atualização**

A pergunta foi alterada de maneira significativa o que me fez editar a resposta.

O resultado não era `10` como mencionado anteriormente, mas `20`, já que é feita uma soma de `b+=i` após o *cast*. Entretanto, isso não altera a explicação, já que 20 é um número que está no intervalo de um `byte` em Java.

Answer (score 4):

Note que a pergunta original dá uma pista equivocada do que realmente foi perguntado no concurso. Agora também não está muito preciso. Em qualquer coisa, mas especialmente em concursos é fundamental ter precisão na interpretação ou comunicação do que é o problema. Caso contrário os erros ocorrerão por causa da deficiência da comunicação mais do que a falta do conhecimento.

No caso a afirmação da questão 127 é verdadeira. Será impresso 20.

```
int i = 10; // i está valendo 10
byte b = 5; // b está valendo 5
b = (byte)i; // agora b passa valer 10, o cast não o afeta, dentro dentro da capacidade do tipo
b += i; //agora b vale o seu próprio valor mais o de i, então 10 de b e 10 de i = 20
i = b; // agora i passa ter o mesmo valor de b, ou seja, 20.
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/CastExample.java).

O *cast* não afetou nada o valor. Ele poderia ter afetado se o valor `i` estivesse fora da faixa aceita pelo tipo *byte* (-128 até 127). O mesmo vale para a adição do valor de `i` em `b`. O valor de `i` que tem 4 bytes de armazenamento "cabia" dentro de `b` que tem apenas 1 byte. O tipo `byte` permite representar 256 números distintos (2 elevado a 8), enquanto que o tipo `int` permite (de -2.147.483.648 à 2.147.483.647 4.294.967.295 - 2 elevado a 32).

Comment: Importante ressaltar também que a soma do inteiro no byte também não afetou visto que os bits do inteiro não passaram do limite do byte, nem usou do último bit que é usado para negativo do byte.

Comment: @DarkHyudrA verdade, melhorei, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Sempre que é feito um cast de um tipo numeral pra byte, entenda os bits que estão envolvidos, no caso do seu exemplo acontece isso:

`00000000 00000000 00000000 00001110`

`00001110`

Ele vai simplesmente descartar tudo a esquerda que seja além do primeiro byte. Vale notar também que o byte do Java tem sinal, então o primeiro bit ajuda a identificar o sinal.

E sobre seu exemplo de código, rode em qual versão de java for, que o resultado sempre vai ser 10 também. Isso gera um comportamento bem estranho, porque, por exemplo, 127 em int é 127 em byte, mas 128 em int é -128 em byte.

Recomendo experimentar comandos como bit shift para entender melhor como a estrutura de dados funciona a nível de bit.

Answer (score 0):

Se executarmos o código abaixo:

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        int i = 10;
        byte b = 5;
        b = (byte) i;
        System.out.println(b); // esta linha irá imprimir 10
     }
 }
```

Será impresso o valor "10". Pois é um valor que cabe numa variável do tipo byte. Mas se eu mudar o código para:

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        int i = 300;
        byte b = 5;
        b = (byte) i;
        System.out.println(b); // esta linha não irá imprimir 10
     }
 }
```

Não será impresso 300. Pois é um valor que não cabe numa variável deste tipo.

Se olhares para a documentação de Java :  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

verás que o `byte` é um tipo de dado inteiro mas bastante limitado. Aceita valores de -128 a 127. Ou seja, valores fora desta margem serão perdidos.

Comment: E o que vai imprimir o último `System.out.println(b);`? Fiquei curioso :P

Comment: no exemplo que usei imprime 44. Vê a resposta do @DarkHyudrA que ele explica porque é que isso acontece